# Select and Copy input text onclick?

Tags: javascript

I've actually seen a few questions about this, most of them are from at least 5 or 6 years ago.

I want to have an input box:

```
<input id="copy-text" type="text" value="Click this text!">
```

Here's the JavaScript I've been trying to work with:

```
document.getElementById("copy-text").onclick = function() {
  this.select();
  execCommand('copy');
  alert('This is a test...');
}
```

I know my code doesn't work. If I remove `execCommand('copy');` then the `alert()` pops up, but it seems to be hitting an error at that line. I've tried making it `this.execCommand('copy');` as well, not really sure what to do here.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6v24k4sk/

The idea is that I want the user to click the input box, it will select all the text, and then copy it to the clipboard.

Any ideas?

Comment: @StephenP no, I'm not very good with JS, I don't even know what that means to be honest with you. Maybe you can provide some insight?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: @Matthew depends on your browser for how to use the developer tools, but try right-click menu and pick "Inspect" or "Inspect Element"; try F12 for IE. BTW, `this.select()` clears the text that was selected (in your fiddle) so the whole content is copied, not the selection. Remove that line and you can click-drag to select text in the textbox, and when you release the mouse button only the selected text is copied to the clipboard.

Comment: @StephenP thanks! Sorry I know how to enter the dev tools, just don't know what that phrase meant you provided that you saw in the console. Thanks for the tip! I'm dynamically making a link with php, so I want everything there to be selected and copied.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should put a *document.* in front of the execCommand.

```
document.getElementById("copy-text").onclick = function() {
    this.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    alert('This is a test...');
}
```

Here you can find a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/9q3c1k20/

edit:

The function also returns whether this functionality is supported in the browser. I think you should check the value, because execCommand still has no final specification and is therefore not guaranteed to work in all browsers.

Comment: Perfect! Out of curiosity, and so I can understand it, why does select() have to be this.select() but execCommand() has to be document.execCommand() but alert() doesn't need anything in front of it?

Comment: @Matthew since you are in a function that is an (onclick) event handler, `this` refers to the object on which the event occurred. In this case, `this` is the `<input ...>` control, so you call `.select()` on that object.  The `execCommand` function is a property of the `document` object, thus `document.execCommand()` ... while plain unqualified `execComand()` is called on the _window_ object, and there is no `window.execCommand` function.

Comment: Thanks for information, I appreciate it. I'm finding JS to be an interesting language to learn - it almost feels messy sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Use this function with your copy_btn (without onclick function).

```
function function_name() {
    var c = document.getElementById("copy");
    c.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```